# Store decimal number into database from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-4.0

I am trying to store decimal numbers into a SQL Server database where column datatype is `numeric(10,2)`.

The data passed from textbox to database using parameterized procedure as below

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PP", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = decimal.Parse(TB_PP.Text);
```

My problem it that I can enter decimal number directly into database table and when read it from database to textbox I get an decimal number

But when storing it through textbox it save an integer so what should I use instead of `SqlDbType.Decimal`?

Comment: That sounds strange. Try saving a hardcoded number like this: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PP", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = 123456.1234m;` See how that gets saved.

Comment: You **should use** `SqlDbType.Decimal` - not something else *instead* .....

Comment: @CodingYoshi I got `123456` it passed and saved and when read into textbox I got '123456' all number after the point are gone when saved into database

Comment: @marc_s then why it is saved ad 123456 not `123456.123`  ?

Comment: Are you sure it is `numeric(10,2)` column? If yes, the issue is not in the code you have posted. You need to post more lines of code after this line because perhaps you are doing something else.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I tried to pass it as `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PP", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = 123456.12345;` and it stored into database as `123456.00`

Answer (score 0):

Try using double instead of a decimal:

```
double.Parse(TB_PP.Text);
```

Comment: I tried to pass it as `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PP", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = 123456.12345;` and it stored into database as `123456.00`

Comment: so saving it as `double.Parse(TB_PP.Text);` wont help

Comment: Try using Math.Round(double.Parse(TB_PP.Text), 2), this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your Parameter this way:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PP", SqlDbType.Decimal) {
    Precision = 10, 
    Scale = 2 
 });
```

My experience is when the SQL data type is `decimal(10,2)` and not `numeric`, but give it a try.